# Want to first save user profile data and then automatically create user

Tags: django, authentication, registration

This application is for a school where the admin(through django admin) can upload the student's data and based on that, a user is created ( username is ID and password is dd/mm/yy).Basically removing the need for all the students to register themselves on the platform.

I've seen videos where signals are used to create profile from user using post_save() but to create user from profile I can't use that since profile editing is also allowed which will trigger post_save() and try to create a user, even though one already exists for that profile.
Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

i guess you want to use signal by which evertime a user created a model also creat for that user which is related to that user by oneonefield
for which we use signal

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

# Create your models here.

class Profile_Pic(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User ,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', default='default.png',)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile_pic(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile_Pic.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile_pic(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile_pic.save()
```

you can also create diffrent signals.py file or you can also write it in your models.py
it works fine and in you views.py use like this

```
def profile(request, username):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Profile_PicForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile_pic)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/@<slug:username>/')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Please Check The File.')
    else:
        return render(request, 'profile.html', {'form':form})
```

what it do evertime a user got sucessfully created it automatically create a model whic belong to that user